# How to generate daily/weekly/monthly/annual aggregate values from a database

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, orm

I am working on an API with Django Rest Framework. I want to generate daily/weekly/monthly/annual **aggregate values for total bookings** that have happened.

I have added an image to give an idea of how the **aggregated weekly data** may look. Here is simplified model. Most of the queries I attempted failed to achieve what I wanted.

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    trans_date = models.DateTime(auto_now_add=True)
    amount_paid = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    trans_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

Here is a query I attempted;

```
weekly_agg = Booking.objects.annotate(week=ExtractWeek('trans_date')).values('trans_date').annotate(count=Count('id')).values('trans_date','count')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution,you can substitute the variables appropriately for daily,weekly etc counts:

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractDay,ExtractWeek,..Month,..Year
from django.db.models import Count

weekly_aggregate = Booking.objects.annotate(week=ExtractWeek('trans_date')).values('week').annotate(count=Count('id')).values('week'
,'count')

#output
<QuerySet [{'week': 3, 'count': 2}, {'week': 7, 'count': 7}, {'week': 20, 'count': 1}, {'week': 19, 'count': 1}, {'week': 1, 'count': 1}]>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's help you to aggregate data:
https://hakibenita.com/django-group-by-sql